# How can I pass a value from a Button_Click event to Page_Load

Tags: c#, asp.net

It seems I am struggling with the order of the page life cycle. Based on the user selecting button 1 or 2, I need to have respective controls added dynamically during the Page_Load event. My problem is when a button is clicked the Page_Load event is executed before Button_Click event code is read. There for my variable "doWhat" is not assigned a value until after the Page_Load event. How can I have the "doWhat" variable assigned a value to be read during the Page_Load?

Below is asp.net form code for the two buttons:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button 1" onclick="Button_Click" />
    <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Button 2" onclick="Button_Click" />
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
</div>
</form>
```

Below is the code behind:

```
 int doWhat;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   doWhat = Convert.ToUInt16(ViewState["doWhat"]);

    if (doWhat == 1)
    {
        // code to dynamically load group 1 controls
    }
    else 
    {
        // code to dynamically load group 2 controls
    }
    Label1.Text = Convert.ToString(doWhat);
}

protected void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = sender as Button;
    if (btn.ID == "Button1")
    {
        doWhat = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        doWhat = 2;
    }
    ViewState.Add("doWhat", doWhat);  
}
```

Comment: Maybe this will be helpful. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: If you need to do it in one request, then your approach isn't correct as Page load executes before Button_Click, and after that it won't be executed again

Comment: Is there any reason you want the dynamic controls to be created in `pageload`? Rather you can encapsulate that code as two different functions and call the respective function in `Button_Click`. In that case the sequence of page life cycle wont affect you.

Comment: Hi Dennis R, Yes I think the controls need to be created in the Page_Load as they will have event handlers attached to them. It seems they need to be created in the Page_Load to work correctly.

Comment: Sergey, yes this is my problem, Do you have a suggestion on how I can pass that variable back to the Page_Load event to be read ?

Comment: How do you load your controls? If just by setting `Visible=true`, then you can that code block to a new method like `UpdateControlsVisibility`, and then call it from `Button_Click` handler.

Comment: See this.http://forums.asp.net/t/1371560.aspx?Determine+the+Control+Events+fired+in+Page+Load+Event

Comment: @LanceM try to do using Request.Form["__EVENTTARGET"]. check answer below

Comment: No you don't have to add controls in Page_Load, This should help you achieve what you are looking for: http://couldbedone.blogspot.com/2007/06/dynamically-created-controls-in-aspnet.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are comfortable with javascript then you can achieve it by making following changes in your design and code. Add a hidden field in your aspx page. Your HTML code should be like this.

```
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button 1" OnClick="Button_Click" OnClientClick="return doWhatAction(1);" />
            <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Button 2" OnClick="Button_Click" OnClientClick="return doWhatAction(2);" />
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
            <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" Value="1" runat="server" />
            <script type="text/javascript">
                var doWhatAction = function (actionIndex) {
                    //alert(actionIndex);
                    document.getElementById("<%=HiddenField1.ClientID%>").value = actionIndex;
                    return true;
                }
            </script>
        </div>
    </form>
```

And your code will be something like...

```
    int doWhat;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //doWhat = Convert.ToUInt16(ViewState["doWhat"]);
        doWhat = Convert.ToUInt16(HiddenField1.Value);

        if (doWhat == 1)
        {
            // code to dynamically load group 1 controls
        }
        else
        {
            // code to dynamically load group 2 controls
        }
        Label1.Text = Convert.ToString(doWhat);
    }

    protected void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Do Nothing

        //Button btn = sender as Button;
        //if (btn.ID == "Button1")
        //{
        //    doWhat = 1;
        //}
        //else
        //{
        //    doWhat = 2;
        //}
        //ViewState.Add("doWhat", doWhat); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery or javascript i  this case.

1. Took on hidden variable in form
2. initialize it on click event of button in javascript
3. Read value of hidden variable in page load

```
<head >
    <title>Hidden Variable</title>
     <script type="text/javascript">
         function SetHDNValue()
         {
            var hdnControlID = '<%= hdnControl.ClientID %>';
            document.getElementById(hdnControlID).value=1;
         }
    </script>
</head>



<body >
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>  
        <input id="hdnControl" type="hidden" runat="server" />  

        <asp:Button ID="btnJSValue" Text="Click" runat="server" OnClientClick="SetHDNValue()" 
/>
    </div>

    </form>
</body>
```

And in code behind file hdnControl.value

Answer (score 0):

Since long  ago I am not working with asp.net forms. And forgot doing things.But I found how you can do. As on stackoverflow link like answers is wrong. I copied main statements from the link which indicate how post-back events works and how you can use it for your purpose. For  more http://aspsnippets.com/Articles/How-to-find-the-control-that-caused-PostBack-in-ASP.Net.aspx

All controls accept Button and ImageButton use JavaScript for causing a postback. **To enable postback on these controls one has to set AutoPostBack property to true**.

When you set this property to true, `__doPostBack`  function is called on event which causes a postback.

The `__doPostBack`  function is not visible in Source of the page until you place a LinkButton or set **AutoPostBack to true** for any of the above discussed controls.

Here is how generated **__doPostBack** looks:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
    theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
    theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
    theForm.submit();
}
}
</script>
```

The `__doPostBack` function simply stores the below two arguments in two hidden fields

1. **eventTarget** – The name of the control that caused the postback
2. **eventArgument** – The argument to be sent to server.

**In two hidden fields which also appear only when AutoPostBack is set to true**

Finally, here is how you can distinguish by getting  *control's ID* that caused the postback :

```
if (IsPostBack)
{
    string CtrlID = string.Empty;
    if (Request.Form["__EVENTTARGET"] != null &&
        Request.Form["__EVENTTARGET"] != string.Empty)
    {
        CtrlID = Request.Form["__EVENTTARGET"];

        /****implement Your logic depending on control ID****/
    }

}
```

Comment: qwr, thanks for the insight. This approach works good. I am able to get the control ID that caused the post back and use it in the Page_Load if I use a control like a check box. I did add the post back attribute to the button but it is not a valid attribute for that control. Any ideas on how I can add it to the button.

Comment: for all checkboxes add  runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" . This way I believe it should call when checkbox will be changed. And I wanted to know you are using checkboxes as toggle button or just options??? If for options then just place one normal button and inside event check for checkbox states